# How to upload files to Firebase Storage using a userId and token obtained through using the REST API

Tags: firebase, rest, react-native, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload a file to upload an image to Firebase Storage with the rule that a user can only write to their own user profile. Below are my storage rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /users/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null; 
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

However when i upload the image, i get an access denied error. I'm sure that I have covered all other angles as to why it has gone wrong. The only thing I can think of is that my userID is not being sent to firebase storage correctly. I get my token and UserId from sending a `POST` request. This is my sign up function

```
return async dispatch => {
        const response = await fetch(
            'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key={MYKEY}',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email: email,
                    password: password,
                    returnSecureToken: true
                })
            }
        );
        if (!response.ok) {
            const errorData = await response.json()
            const errorId = errorData.error.message;
            let message = 'Something went wrong!'
            if (errorId === 'EMAIL_EXISTS') {
                message = 'The email entered already exists';
            }
            throw new Error(message);
        }
        const resData = await response.json()
      dispatch(authenticate(resData.localId,resData.idToken,parseInt(resData.expiresIn) * 1000, resData.refreshToken))
```

Are there any compatibility issues with the token and userId you get form the REST API and firebase storage. And if there is, what is the solution to uploading images to firebase storage.

This is also my uploadImage function.

```
const uploadImage = async (uri, name) => {
        const response = await fetch(uri);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        console.log(response)
        console.log(blob)
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
        var profilePhotoRef = storageRef.child(`users/${uid}/${name}`);
        return profilePhotoRef.put(blob);
    };
```

Thanks.

Comment: So you're not using the Firebase Authentication SDK at all?

Comment: Hi. Im using the stuff from here. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth. Not completely sure if its Firebase Authentication SDK or not because im still really new to react native and app dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only when you use the [Firebase Authentication SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) to sign in the user will the user's ID be sent along with file uploads and downloads for use in security rules.  Manually authenticating with the REST API will not work.